# Save multiple items that share the same categoryId

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using SQLite with EFCore. I am trying to save several items that are part of the same category, but when I try to save them I am getting a foreign key constraint error.

The Error: "SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'."

The models look like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName {get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<Item>? Items { get; set; }
}
```

So a category can have a lot of items and many of them will each have the same category ID as a foreign key. Is this possible with SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

Your models are not configured right. Please, check the [following article](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration) and configure your models as described.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

 public class Category
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Do they actually have to be setup that way? I typically use Postgres (Npgsql) for my sever projects, and I setup my models exactly as above and the relationships all work just fine. Is this a SQLite specific requirement?

Comment: `public int Category { get; set; }` - this is not right. If you want to configure your entity to have both FK value and navigation property (which IS usually good idea), the navigation property must be of type `Category`. But it doesn't solve the original problem, having dual FK/navigation is NOT required. See my answer for another attempt, if it doesn't help we might need full repro. Contents of DbContextModelSnapshot.cs might help too, if the project uses migration.

Comment: @huancz I Agree, It would also cause a couple of other issues, like cycle errors. I am going to test out your solution below, hoping that will work out. If not, im probably storing json files.

Comment: @huancz a good eye, I have changed the name and forgot to change the type. I edited the property. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem might be in the `[ForeignKey]` attribute. Models like this should configure themselves by convention (you have `List<Item>` on `Category`, that is enough for EF Core to know what you mean).

I never used the `ForeignKeyAttribute` to configure my models, but documentation sounds like it specifies name of the property in the OTHER table that it should use as foreign key to reference this entity. Used like this I would expect EF to just reject the model as invalid, or create some sort of self-referencing Item. Try moving it to `Category.Items`. Or just get rid of it.

For comparison, equivalent fluent configuration would be:

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
{
    builder
        .HasMany(x => x.Items)
        .WithOne(/* x => x.Category - this would apply if you had dual Category/CategoryId on Item */)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId);
}
```

Here we start on category table, specify the other table and `HasForeignKey` says what column in the other table it should use.

Answer (score -1):

Have a try like below:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName {get; set; }
    
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category? Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<Item>? Items { get; set; }
}
```